# Как сгенерировать исключение которое не будет приводить к завершению работы приложения?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-basic

Для тестирования функционала своего приложения решил написать простенькую тестовую программу с которой будет работать моё приложение.

В тестовой программе необходимо кроме всего прочего генерировать исключение которое **не будет** приводить к завершению работы приложения.

Вопрос: Как это сделать? Просто вызов `throw new Exception()` приводит к завершению приложения.

Возможно мой вопрос не совсем понятен, поясню: я запускаю некоторую программу посредством Process.Start(); И перенаправляю на себя StandardError stream. Как выглядит ситуация когда запущенная программа выкидывает эксепшн и закрывается мне ясно и я его обрабатываю. А вот как смоделировать ситуацию когда приложение выкидывает эксепшн и продолжает работу мне неизвестно, собсна в этом и вопрос.

Пример эксепшена: http://blogsisadmina.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/1.png 
В консольном приложении повторение финта с индексом всё равно приводит к завершению работы приложения.

Comment: Почему бы его просто не перехватить с помощью catch?

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос. Тестовая программа должна имитировать поведение некой программы которая может отвалится с критическим эксепшеном, а может просто вывести сообщение об ошибке и предложить продолжить работу.  И мне важно в моем приложении уметь выявлять подобные ситуации.

Comment: Возможно мой вопрос не совсем понятен, поясню: я запускаю некоторую программу посредством Process.Start();  И перенаправляю на себя StandartError stream. 
Как выглядит ситуация когда запущенная программа выкидывает эксепшн и закрывается мне ясно и я его обрабатываю. 
А вот как смоделировать ситуацию когда приложение выкидывает эксепшн и продолжает работу мне неизвестно, собсна в этом и вопрос.

Comment: @AlexeyGrebenyukov Если у вас есть полный доступ к коду (да даже просто дотнетовая сборка), то смысла в запуске процесса с попыткой ловили исключений в чужом процессе — ноль. Просто вызывайте нужный код напрямую, можно в отдельном AppDomain.

Comment: Доступа к чужому коду нет. Сборка вполне может быть и не дотнетовской.

Comment: @AlexeyGrebenyukov чтобы смоделировать некритическое исключение, можно же просто показать `MessageBox.Show("Error");` Или, например, перехватывать исключения и показывать `MessageBox` с текстом ошибки. Ваш вопрос все еще не совсем понятен.

Comment: @AlexeyGrebenyukov Если чужое нативное приложение решило упасть с AV, например, извне вы его никак спасти не можете. Поэтому советую решать задачу не в общем виде, а определиться с тем, что именно и в каком объёме вам надо.

Comment: _приложение выкидывает эксепшн и продолжает работу_ - это невозможно. Вероятно, вы имели в виду, что приложение что-то пишет в **Стандартный поток ошибки**. Но это вовсе не выброс исключения (Exception).

Comment: Мне нужен вот такой эксепшн: http://blogsisadmina.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/1.png

Comment: _Сборка вполне может быть и не дотнетовской._ - а с этим как быть?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Все исключения должны быть отловлены. Это означает, что где-то в стеке вызовов должен быть try-catch, который проглотит исключение и, например, залогирует его. Хорошим тоном является отлавливание только исключений, которые вы предполагаете, а не просто базового типа исключения, потому что иначе вы можете прозевать проблемную ситуацию и получить повреждение данных где-то в другом месте, в результате поиск проблемы значительно усложнится.

```
try {
    DoSomething();
}
catch (FooException e) {
    Log.LogException(e);
}

// ...

DoSomething() {
    throw new FooException();
}
```

Если вы хотите запрятать от клиентов падучесть приложения и считаете, что важнее отсутствие падений, чем стабильная работа и отсутствие повреждений данных, то можете отлавливать разнообразные события unhandled exception (они есть у домена, задач, диспетчера) и отмечать исключения как обработанные, если это возможно. В этом случае приложение продолжит работать, но за состояние данных никто не будет отвечать.

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.UnhandledException += CurrentDispatcher_UnhandledException;
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException;
```

Если исключения не будет нигде отловлены, то приложение упадёт, и информация об ошибке попадёт с системный журнал. Это не самый удобный способ, но им тоже можно пользоваться.

Comment: Угу, но я бы назвал стратегию, описанную в предпоследнем абзаце, стратегией страуса.

Comment: Мне в моем приложении необходимо отслеживать поведение "чужой" программы и скрупулезно записывать все вылеты/зависания/ошибки и при этом желательно не влиять ни коим образом на работу программы.

Comment: @AlexeyGrebenyukov Если вам нужно взаимодействие с абсолютно чужой программой, это один случай. Если вы отвечаете за обе программы (и обе на дотнете), то можно не создавать процесс, а просто вызывать нужный код. Можно в отдельном домене, чтобы обезопаситься.

Comment: @VladD Стратегия страуса — это скорее `try { Foo(); } catch { }`. :) А когда приложение падает, это хорошо заметно. Если установлен отладчик, ещё и запустить его предлагается.

Comment: @Discord: Угу, я имел в виду именно ловлю всех исключений.

Comment: @VladD Ну почему, у меня есть славный костыль [UnhandledExceptionsHandler](https://github.com/Athari/Alba.Framework/blob/516426e4782659dfb1413c131528e9eb6a754b6d/Alba.Framework/Diagnostics/UnhandledExceptionsHandler.cs). По вкусу: можно логировать и падать, можно предлагать юзеру продолжить работу на свой страх и риск, можно молча глотать. :)

Comment: @z668 Пока вы не лезете в unsafe и interop, у вас всё проверяется, и вы не можете никуда вылезти. Когда вы лезете в unsafe, может произойти абсолютно что угодно, и никто не сможет вас остановить.

Answer (score 5):

Используйте `try {..} catch(){}`

В блоке try вбрасываете исключение, с catch его ловите.

```
int a = 5;
try {
    if (a == 5) {
        throw new Exception("a > 5!");
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Возникла ошибка!");
}
```

Обратите внимание, что тип ошибки вбрасываемой ошибки должен совпадать с типом перехватываемой ошибки.
Подробнее про try/catch: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0yd65esw.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

В общем я видимо только всех запутал... 
Мне необходимо было сгенерить подобный эксепшн: http://blogsisadmina.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/1.png 
Проблема заключалась в том, что в консольном приложении генерация любого не перехваченного эксепшена приводила к завершению работы. И связано это судя по всему с тем, в какой поток консоль пишет исключения.

Решение проблемы: использовать не консольное а winforms/wpf приложение. В этом случае любой эксепшн (ну или почти любой, все не проверял) выдаст требуемое окно с вариантом "продолжить".

PS:Ну а поскольку мой вопрос был весьма сумбурным и лейб мотивом всё же была обработка и перехват эксепшенов То в качестве верного ответа я, пожалуй, укажу самый популярный на текущий момент ответ. Для большинства приходящих судя из гугла это будет то, что нужно, а тем кто будет искать ответ на тот же вопрос что и я не составит труда прочесть все комментарии

Comment: В вопросе вы написали: _запускаю некоторую программу посредством Process.Start()_. Если запустите консольную программу, она упадёт без возможности продолжения.  Вы уж всё-таки определитесь, какую программу хотите написать: запускатель или запускаемую.

Comment: "Для тестирования функционала своего приложения решил написать простенькую тестовую программу с которой будет работать моё приложение. "  этим я хотел сказать что у меня уже есть программа которую я написал и для тестирования её работы хотел написать ещё одну с функционалом по которому у меня и был вопрос.

Приведённая вами цитата по моему разумению должна была проиллюстрировать детали взаимодействия моей основной программы с тестовой.